# How do I return a sum of all entries in a list

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on this `NumberList` class which represents a list of integers. The `NumberList` object has just one instance variable `values`, which is a reference to an array of `int` values. One of the methods I need to implement is supposed to return the sum of all entries in the list.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
  public long getTotal() 
{

        long total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            total += values[i];

        }

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: instead of return, you should create representative that points the array calculate the sum and assign the value.

Comment: Please refrain from removing your question after it is solved.  Add any further messages as a comment, or as an additional edit in the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop is going up to `total`, but that's (probably) not the size of your array, it's `values.length`.

Comment: oh yeah you're right it should be values.length.  thanks for pointing that out.  it should work correctly now

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminates immediately because of `i < total`

You initially set `total = 0`, so the operation inside the loop is never executed, as i is never less than 0.